# How to log malformed rows from Scala Spark DataFrameReader csv

Tags: scala, csv, logging, apache-spark

The documentation for the [Scala_Spark_DataFrameReader_csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv(java.lang.String)) suggests that spark can log the malformed rows detected while reading a .csv file.
- How can one log the malformed rows?
- Can one obtain a val or var containing the malformed rows?

The option from the linked documentation is:
maxMalformedLogPerPartition (default 10): sets the maximum number of malformed rows Spark will log for each partition. Malformed records beyond this number will be ignored

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [databricks example](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/read-csv-corrupt-record.html) you need to explicitly add the "_corrupt_record" column to a schema definition when you read in the file. Something like this worked for me in pyspark 2.4.4:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

my_schema = StructType([
  StructField("field1", StringType(), True),
  ...
  StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), True)
])

my_data = spark.read.format("csv")\
  .option("path", "/path/to/file.csv")\
  .schema(my_schema)
  .load()

my_data.count()  # force reading the csv

corrupt_lines = my_data.filter("_corrupt_record is not NULL")
corrupt_lines.take(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the spark 2.3 check the _corrupt_error special column ... according to several spark discussions "it should work " , so after the read filter those which non-empty cols - there should be your errors ... you could check also the input_file_name() sql func

if you are not using lower than version 2.3 you should implement a custom read , record solution, because according to my tests the _corrupt_error does not work for csv data source ...

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded on [klucar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551943/4371444)'s answer here by loading the csv, making a schema from the non-corrupted records, adding the corrupted record column, using the new schema to load the csv and then looking for corrupted records.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

file_path = "/path/to/file"
mode = "PERMISSIVE"

schema = spark.read.options(mode=mode).csv(file_path).schema
schema = schema.add(StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), True))

df = spark.read.options(mode=mode).schema(schema).csv(file_path)
df.cache()
df.count()
df.filter(col("_corrupt_record").isNotNull()).show()
```